# Should I be concerned with a minute amount of flexing under a shower tray?

Tags: shower, mortar

I have recently installed a quadrant shower tray.  The manufacturer recommends a 5:1 sand and cement base on an 18mm structural marine ply to support the tray.  The tray was set on a 18mm sand and cement depth and the tray adjusted into it to give a visible 10mm base.  The structure of the timber subfloor is very good with no noticeable deflection (glass test).

After two weeks, I have noticed that front sand and cement base has a minute gap between the floor and the tray. On inspection I noticed that the tray flexes a minute amount (probably a 1mm) on the outer edge. The shower screen is yet to be installed, so this will apply some weight to hopefully reduce this effect.  I understand that sand and cement base is to support the tray and not to bond to it to allow for some building movement

**However, should I be concerned with this?**

Assuming that the floor is solid, could it be that the sand and cement mix might have shrunk?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't sound serious. You're probably right that the masonry has shrunk a bit. I doubt that's enough flex to cause damage over time, and if you're able to press it down with the shower walls, all good. Chances are it'll settle a bit and you won't see any movement after a while.